Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в выражении "работайте, как работали"?
Если существует такая необходимость, сократите количество сотрудников, а если нет – работайте, как работали.

"если нет - работайте" - звучит? Вот ещё для сравнения: Работу найду везде… — Нет, работайте как работали. Никуда я вас не отпущу, вы хороший работник.//
И Любимову позвонили и удивленно сказали: «Никто вас не снимал, работайте, как работали».

Правильно:
Если существует такая необходимость, сократите количество сотрудников, а если нет – рабОтайте (так), как рабОтали.

Это СПП с придаточным образа действия, нет причин для отсутствия запятой.

Необособленный устойчивый оборот с подчинительным союзом? Нет, не похоже. Сравнить: Работайте как хотите.

Из Нацкорпуса:

Майя Кучерская. Современный патерик: чтение для впавших в уныние (2004). Лучше уж рабОтайте, как рабОтали, и не ропщите».
А. И. Кондратович. Дневник (1968).
И Любимову позвонили и удивленно сказали: «Никто вас не снимал, рабОтайте, как рабОтали».

Но (авторский вариант): Октем Эминов. Будь осторожен, Бекназар! (1978). Работу найду везде… — Нет, работайте как рабОтали. Никуда я вас не отпущу, вы хороший работник.

Подчеркнутое обстоятельственное значение (ударение переходит на оборот).
